# create intellij java ee project

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

Can anyone please help me make a hello word in java and using IntelliJ ?
I've tried a lot, but it always says not found.
[my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Oll.png)

Comment: Please specify in which step "not found" error occurs? 
You can try this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u18bz_zLhec

Comment: Jetbrains has an excellent documentation on this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html

Comment: thanks guys, for the help. but i resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to warn you, if anyone else goes through this. you have to add the jar to the artifact.
Following :

```
file -> structure of project -> artifacts.
```

then right click on your project and "put into in output root"